# how to go on next viewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

In my app i have tried to make different class for api calling. like click on login button and its call the method of different class. but when i want to go to another viewcontroller from that different class its getting crash.

here is my code in loginViewController

```
let mydata = DataControllerLogin()
    mydata.login(txtemail.text!,password: txtPassword.text!)

class DataControllerLogin: UIViewController {

func login(username:String,password:String)
{
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
    {
        let url = "\(basicURL)login"
        let param : [String : AnyObject] = [

            "email" : username,
            "password" : password
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON).responseObject(completionHandler: { (response:Response<LoginCode, NSError>) in

            if (response.result.value != nil)
            {

                let LoginCode = response.result.value

                let message = LoginCode?.Message
                let detail = LoginCode?.result

                if (LoginCode?.Status == 1)
                {
                    let controller : LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
                else
                {
                    alertViewShow(self, title: "Sorry", message: message!)
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                }
                if let threedayForecast = LoginCode?.result {

                    print(threedayForecast.FirstName)

                }
            } 
            else
            {

            }  
        })
    }
    else {
        alertViewShow(self, title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.")
    }
}
}
```

but its getting crash on line wherever i have define viewController.

```
let controller : LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

its showing error like

```
exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

so if you know please let me know what is the issue?

Comment: Check LoginViewController has identifer LoginViewController in storyboard?

Comment: already checked that its have a same identifier

Comment: your "DataControllerLogin" is not in stack or not in navigation controller.

Comment: got it man but how can i change my code so its work perfectly. @Er.ShreyanshShah

Comment: @Jack.Right :- I have add one more Parameter in ur method. One more suggestion please make "DataControllerLogin" class of NSObject class.

Comment: Embed your DataControllerLogin with UINavigationController in storyboard.

Comment: Else you can add completion handler in "DataControllerLogin" and use it in your "LoginViewController"

Comment: can you please write a code for completion handler@Er.ShreyanshShah

Comment: @Jack.Right :- Please check updated ans.

Comment: @Jack.Right Please check the storyboard identifier is correct as well as check navigation controller is embed or not to ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Write this at the top of the file.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

typealias SOAPICompletionHandler = (code:Int, error:NSError?, response:NSDictionary?) -> Void
```

Add below method in your file:-

```
func callApi(strApiName:String, param : [String : AnyObject]?, type:String, header:[String : String]?, completionHandler:SOAPICompletionHandler) {
        //let strURL : String = BASEURL+"/"+strApiName
        let strURL = strApiName;
        if type == POSTREQ {
            Alamofire.request(.POST, strURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) -> Void in
                let isSuccess = JSON(responseData.result.isSuccess)
                if isSuccess {
//                    let swiftyJson = JSON(responseData.result.value! as! NSDictionary) as! AnyObject
                    completionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response: responseData.result.value! as? NSDictionary)
                } else {
                    let error = responseData.result.error! as NSError
                    completionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response: nil)
                }
            })
        } else if type == GETREQ {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, strURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) -> Void in
                let isSuccess = JSON(responseData.result.isSuccess)
                if isSuccess {
//                    let swiftyJson = JSON(responseData.result.value! as! NSDictionary)
                    completionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response: responseData.result.value! as? NSDictionary)
                } else {
                    let error = responseData.result.error! as NSError
                    completionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response: nil)
                }
            })
        } else if type == PUTREQ{

            Alamofire.request(.PUT, strURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) -> Void in
                let isSuccess = JSON(responseData.result.isSuccess)
                if isSuccess {
                    //                    let swiftyJson = JSON(responseData.result.value! as! NSDictionary)
                    completionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response: responseData.result.value! as? NSDictionary)
                } else {
                    let error = responseData.result.error! as NSError
                    completionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response: nil)
                }
            })

        } else if type == DELETEREQ{

            Alamofire.request(.DELETE, strURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) -> Void in
                let isSuccess = JSON(responseData.result.isSuccess)
                if isSuccess {
                    //                    let swiftyJson = JSON(responseData.result.value! as! NSDictionary)
                    completionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response: responseData.result.value! as? NSDictionary)
                } else {
                    let error = responseData.result.error! as NSError
                    completionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response: nil)
                }
            })

        }
        else if type == PATCHREQ{

            Alamofire.request(.PATCH, strURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) -> Void in
                let isSuccess = JSON(responseData.result.isSuccess)
                if isSuccess {
                    //                    let swiftyJson = JSON(responseData.result.value! as! NSDictionary)
                    completionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response: responseData.result.value! as? NSDictionary)
                } else {
                    let error = responseData.result.error! as NSError
                    completionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response: nil)
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

you need to add Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Hope for best.

Comment: i dont know why but its not allowed me to define viewcontroller. its giving me error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value